# java applet is it possible to make an applet into png file

Tags: java, image, applet, png, paint

Hi im new to programming and im starting to program with java im creating a program that will paint in the applet and everything seems good.

The thing is i want to save the paint that i have done and i was wondering it is possible to convert that applet or the paint method to png file. If not i was working on that everytime the user paint it will save the coordinates, color and size and save it in txt then i have to create a reader or a display for it.

Is it possible to make an applet to png file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert an **image** into a png file by using `ImageIO.write(...)`. Hopefully it should be fairly easy to extract the image from your painting, but this depends on much that has not yet been shown to us. Please show us your pertinent code so that I can improve this answer with concrete code.

Assuming that you're drawing within a JPanel's paintComponent method or an Applet's paint method, then you can instead paint into a BufferedImage, and then use that Image to convert to your png file.

The other issue is writing from the applet itself to the file on the disk, and there may be permission issues with this. Myself, I avoid programming applets like the plague, since they're really not used much any more, and in fact some browsers don't allow use of them.